# Javascript summing arrays with using d3.nest()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I would like to create a pie chart by grouping "age" and summing population. How could I do that?

**Data.csv**

```
age,population
<5,2704659
5-13,4499890
5-13,4
14-17,2159981
18-24,3853788
18-24,385
25-44,14106543
45-64,8819342
45-64,8142000
5-13,4499000
=65,612463
```

**... should be so:**

```
age,population
<5,2704659
5-13,8998894
14-17,2159981
18-24,3854173
25-44,14106543
45-64,16961342
=65,612463
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

    var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) { return d.age; })
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .rollup(function (d) {
            return d3.sum(d, function (g) { return g.population; });
  }).entries(data);


  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });

});

</script>
```

Can you see a way to modify this function so that it returns the desired result?

Comment: What result are you currently getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summing you are doing is correct, there is no problem with nesting.

The problem is with the values you are setting

*Your code:*

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });
```

Should have been

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  });
```

Similarly in the rendering part for the path and text

```
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.key);///Not d.data.age
    });

  g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.key;///Not d.data.age as returned by data(pie(data))
    });
```

Full working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VuMWTpB6TcBu1tYHCD2e?p=preview)

Hope this helps!